# PHP Namespace Global

Tags: php, namespaces

Is there a way to get a PHP namespace to allow for calling functions within a namespace as if they were global?

Example:

```
handle()
```

Rather than:

```
prggmr\handle()
```

Here is my example code:

```
<?php
require_once 'prggmr/src/prggmr.php';

prggmr\handle(function() {
  echo 'This is a test scenario';
}, 'test');

prggmr\signal('test');
```

Aliasing does not work for functions:

```
<?php
require 'prggmr/src/prggmr.php';
use prggmr\handle;

handle(function(){
    echo "Test";
}, "test");
```

Results:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function handle()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding this excerpt from the documentation says it's not possible ...

> Neither functions nor constants can be imported via the use statement.

Source:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.nofuncconstantuse

Answer (score 2):

Not for a whole namespace, no. But for single names, you can do

```
use p\handle;
```

which [aliases](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) `p\handle` to just `handle`.

Comment: Hi thanks I have tried this. The thing is that the main file is namespaced: prggmr, this is giving me an undefined: ---- <?php  use prggmr as p;
use p\handle as handle;

handle(function() {echo 1;}, 'hey');
signal('hey'); --- I have also tried \handle as a global but that wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add an answer for modern PHP as I recently learned that:

> Before PHP 5.6 neither functions nor constants can be imported via the use statement.
>   As of PHP 5.6 aliasing or importing function and constant names is allowed.

So your second code sample should work just fine these days.

Also worth mentioning that you can define a block scope for PHP namespaces, [though it's discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php). So this would work:

```
<?php
require_once 'prggmr/src/prggmr.php';

namespace prggmr {
    handle(function() {
      echo 'This is a test scenario';
    }, 'test');

    signal('test');
}
```